# Booking.com: can multiple people manage one booking?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, security, booking.com

Well, what the title says. I have a booking but none of my payment cards works for the pre-payment. I asked a relative if I could use their card, but they are hundreds of kilometres away from me. So we have the following options:

1. They send me their card number by mail/SMS/skype/phone...: **very unsafe**
2. I send them my login information for booking.com: **fine with me (I trust them) but still doesn't sound correct**
3. I share/transmit the booking into their account: **however, I haven't found such option in booking.com**

So the question is: Can we do Option 3 somehow, or will we have to stick to Option 2?

Comment: You could get the credit card details over the phone. For added safety you could make sure your friend is at home and not sitting in a public place yelling out the numbers. Yes this might be suboptimal but will leave no tangible traces: no written messages/emails/skype chats/etc. I don't see the need to be paranoid. The NSA might get a hold of your friend's credit card number, but I bet they already have that. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO Yeah, I considered this as well, especially since I'm in a hurry now and they're not at the internet. Well, I'll leave it the question as is for some time, if no better thing is found, I'll re-word it so that your comments fits as an answer. Is it fine with you?

Comment: @JoErNanO That's what I meant. Well, you can probably post the answer even now, I'll just wait with the accepting to see if some other solution is found.

Comment: For added security you can split the number and give one figure or two in an email and the rest on the phone, or such strategy - the phone is more secure than the email though, so give more information over the phone than in the email.

Comment: Giving a credit card number over SMS, skype or phone might not be a “best practice” but isn't it a bit of stretch to consider it “very unsafe”?

Comment: @Relaxed I agree with the phone/skype call (voice, moreover in this crazy language we do speak) being somewhat acceptable, but any logged means are a strict no-no. If not for another reason, just for the fact that your card insurance can be void/limited if you do that.

Comment: @tohecz Seriously? You share your credit card number with any number of vendors and other people you have no way of evaluating, I always thought it was only your PIN number that's supposed to be kept secret. I have often had hotels request a number over the phone or even email, incidentally and while I can see that an email is a very weak channel on a technical level I am not even sure the risk is that great in practice. Maybe something to ask about at the Infosec site…

Comment: @Relaxed (getting a bit chatty and off-topic here, aren't we?) Well, there's likely certain legal difference between sharing the number with a vendor (who had to register with VISA to be able to do the payments) and sharing it with anybody else. I'm not an expert though, these are just my thoughts). And yeah, I had to share a card number once over an e-mail and I really hated doing it.

Comment: Whilst this does not answer the question of sharing bookings on booking.com, if you have to get the credit card number from your friend, **I suggest you to have the conversation over the phone**. This way no tangible traces remain of the conversation -- no text messages/emails/chat logs/etc. For added security you should make sure your friend is at home rather than sitting in a public place yelling out credit card numbers. Is there a chance someone might be eavesdropping the conversation? Probably. However I don't see the need to be paranoid about this. The NSA might get a hold of your friend'

Comment: This is not to make any bad impression about booking.com (I have their genius status), but whatever you do, the hotel itself gets your card number in certain cases.  When you make your booking, check the hotel's payment method. If they charge any authorization, the hotel gets your card information. If you pay by cash, you just pay by cash and booking.com don't even authorize a payment unless you no-show.

Answer (score 1):

OTAs usually allow third party payments, but it is normally the 3rd party that does the booking ie: your relative makes a booking and pays for it with on your behalf. That way their address, contact and payment information is in the record and you are listed as the room occupant only.

In your case, you have already made the booking so your address and contact info is part of the booking. This would cause their payment to be declined due to address mis-match.

Why not check to see if you can make the same booking again (see if the rooms and rate are still available). If they are, cancel your current booking and then get your relative on the phone and have them make / pay for a new booking.

Otherwise your best bet is to call booking.com and see if they will allow a third party payment from outside the original booking.  Some OTAs do have a payment form that can be filled out and signed, so that an outside party can pay.

Comment: Well, what exactly I am supposed to do on the booking.com website?

Comment: For which suggestion?

Comment: I have done the booking, and now I need someone else to make the payment. Your answer doesn't seem to say anything about it. What is OTA? Why do you say "your relative makes a booking" when the booking has been made months ago by me?  How can they even try to pay for it while the card info is supposed to be submitted through my profile on booking.com?

Comment: OTA - Online Travel Agent.  If you are adamant about them paying for your existing booking, then you need to call booking.com and ask the procedure.

Comment: wow, I was confused, totally read OTA as Over the Air.